# yii2 install, configure and run codeception tests

Tags: yii2, codeception

I'm writing this because yii2 official documentation is still not complete and codeception documentation itself refer to yii2 official docs..:).

I have some questions:

- In my yii2 app root there is a directory "tests/codeception", this means that codeception is already installed in my project?
- in vendor/yiisoft there is another codeception directory "yii2-codeception" what is it?
- the documentation say to create a yii2_basic_tests database and to run a migration, but migration script create only a "migration" table, is it correct?
- the integration with yii2 provide some web interface or I must run the tests from console scripts?

Someone can explain me how to install and configure codeception in yii2 basic app step by step?

Thank you

Alessandro

Answer (score 11):

I am doing some like that:

```
composer global require "codeception/codeception=2.0.*" "codeception/specify=*" "codeception/verify=*"
```

And next:

```
ln -s ~/.composer/vendor/bin/codecept /usr/local/bin/codecept
```

Then I am available to do globally

```
codecept run
```

Comment: Are you able to use Yii2's Fixtures in that way?

Answer (score 6):

First make sure you read this a couple of times http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-test-environment-setup.html

Afterwards the actual tests are easy to set up. Make sure you make the codecept command work like it says on the last line of the link above. After you install an Yii app you have to go to the tests folder and run

```
codecept build
```

to initialise the tests. Then run

```
codecept run
```

to run the actual tests.

You can run

```
codecept run --coverage-html
```

to get the code coverage for your project.

I have never got the acceptance testing working with code coverage but I got acceptance working without coverage and unit&functional with coverage.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've managed to install codeception and run a first acceptance test, but only with official 
codeception  [php composer.phar require "codeception/codeception:*" ] comand instead of those mentioned in yii2 guiide. 
It has a codeception (and other) directory in my vendor root. Is it correct?

Comment: This worked for me but I had to run codecept from the vendor/bin. `../vendor/bin/codecept run` I also had to make sure I codeception was installed in my composer, wasn't done as part of yii-codeception

Comment: I created a global link for codeception so I can run it from anywhere. You can do that too as it is quite handy.

Comment: Like i said in the answer, the last line of the link tells you how to set up codeception globally.